# How to measure sinuosity in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcmap

I am trying to quantify the sinuosity of a GPS track (shows a loop pattern) and cannot seem to find any way to do this. I need to be able to quantify sinuosity for the removal of some unwanted data.

Is there a tool to measure sinuosity in arcmap, i am very unfamiliar with the codes in ArcMap 10?

Answer (score 6):

Wikipedia defines [sinuosity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinuosity) as:

> the ratio of the curvilinear length (along the curve) and the distance
>   (straight line) between the end points of the curve

So to calculate this in ArcGIS, you would need to determine:

- the curvilinear length of the line. You can [use the Field Calculator](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000027000000)
- the start and end points of the line. See [this Stack Exchange answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88092/calculating-x-and-y-of-line-start-and-line-end-using-arcpy)
- the straight-line length of the line. You can use [Pythagorean' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem)

Answer (score 4):

If you define sinuosity as a measure of the deviation of a line from the shortest path (dividing total length by shortest possible path), on http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=00e708a448b74810a0e805c4a97f9d46, you can get a python toolbox "Calculate sinuosity" to it. Just download it and load it in ArcToolBox to make the script available.

Note that the Hawth's Analysis Tools for ArcGIS (http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/tooldesc.php) offers also a tool called LINE METRICS TOOL which computes sinuosity or fractal dimension of line but is limited to ArcGis9.2.

Comment: They actually include the code for this toolbox as an example in the [help files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000022000000) as well.